# Capturing text between n slashes using bash

Tags: bash

I have a file with a list of URLs. I'd like to capture the text between slashes N and N+1 and place it in a variable.

I'd also like to remove everything after the last slash.

Example:
https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt

1. Capture the text between the 2nd and 3rd slashes and yield "example.com"
2. Capture the text between the 3rd and 4th slashes and yield "dir1"
3. Capture the text between the 4th and 5th slashes and yield "dir2"
4. And so on...
5. Finally, identify "file.txt" as the end of the URL, remove it and yield "https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/

The URLs may contain varying numbers of slashes from 3 up to 30.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example input file with 3 lines and the corresponding output? `echo "${url%/*}/"` works for a variable with one url, but how should the converted inputfile look like?

Comment: Please post a separate question for "removing everything after the last slash" (which can be accomplished with `sed 's:.*/::' inputfile`)

Comment: "Capture" and do what? Store it in a variable?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

Use the bash feature allowing to remove prefixes and suffixes from a string:

```
url="https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt"
echo $url

https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt

path=${url%/*}
echo $path

https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3

result=${path##*/}
echo $result

dir3
```

No need to loop over the path.

I am not sure if the PO is asking $path or $result as answer.

Comment: the command **dirname** achieves the same result as `${url%/*}`

Comment: Parameter Expansion is not just a bash feature. see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06  It is defined by POSIX, although bash has some PE's that is not found/defined/allowed in POSIX. but what you have there has nothing specific to bash afaik.

Comment: @Jetchisel: How would you call more accurately something that is described in the manual of Bash? Your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I would just call it P.E. Parameter Expansion, since there is no bash specific P.E. in your solution, is all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.

1.Capture the text between the 2nd and 3rd slashes and yield "example.com"

```
 url=https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt
 url=${url%"${url#*http*.*/}"}
 url=${url%/*}
 echo "${url##*/}"
 example.com
```

2.Capture the text between the 3rd and 4th slashes and yield "dir1"

```
url=https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt
url1=${url%"${url#*http*.*/}"}
url1=${url#*"${url1}"}
echo "${url1%%/*}"
dir1
```

3.Capture the text between the 4th and 5th slashes and yield "dir2"

```
url=https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt
url1=${url%"${url#*http*.*/}"}
url1=${url#*"${url1}"}
url1=${url1#*/}
echo "${url1%%/*}"
dir2
```

4 -----

5.Finally, identify "file.txt" as the end of the URL, remove it and yield https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/

```
url=https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt
echo "${url%/*}"
https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/
```

At least that's how I understood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do                     # read the input records line by line
    echo "${line%/*}/"                          # print the url removing the portion after the last slash
    IFS="/" read -ra ary <<< "$line"            # split the url on slashes and store the result in an array
    for ((i=2; i<${#ary[@]}; i++)); do          # iterate over the array from the 2nd elemnt to the last one
        printf "ary[%d]=%s\n" "$i" "${ary[i]}"  # print each element of the array
    done
    # do whatever here using the variables above
done << EOS
https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt
http://foo.bar.com/dirA/dirB/dirC/dirD/baz.txt
EOS
```

Output:

```
https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/
ary[2]=example.com
ary[3]=dir1
ary[4]=dir2
ary[5]=dir3
ary[6]=file.txt
http://foo.bar.com/dirA/dirB/dirC/dirD/
ary[2]=foo.bar.com
ary[3]=dirA
ary[4]=dirB
ary[5]=dirC
ary[6]=dirD
ary[7]=baz.txt
```

Of course you can feed the list of urls from a file.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` deals with *fields*. Consider your delimiter as `'/'` and `awk` makes separation trivial, e.g.

```
$ echo "https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt" | 
awk -F/ '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(length($i)) print "field[" i "]: " $i}'
field[1]: https:
field[3]: example.com
field[4]: dir1
field[5]: dir2
field[6]: dir3
field[7]: file.txt
```

Since the `awk` internal variable `NF` provides the number of fields automatically, it makes no difference how many slashes you have. Using the `length()` command you can simply skip the empty-field between `'//'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract specific field, you can use `cut`

`cut -f FIELD_NUM -d  '/' <(echo "URL")`

Example:

`cut -f 3 -d  '/' <(echo "https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt")
=> example.com`

`cut -f 5 -d  '/' <(echo "https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt")
=> dir2`